# list index out of range when trying to access a specific list item

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and can't figure out why this simple code doesn't work:

I have a string (a message like `handposition/506.83047/388.1101/703.2166` from my websocket client) with `/` as separator and want to split it into a list:

```
coordinates = msg.split('/')
```

I can print the list with:

```
print(coordinates)
```

and get this:

```
['handposition', '495.0279', '443.24762', '976.6502']
```

Everything works until I try to access the second element in the list with:

```
print(coordinates[1])
```

I get this error message:

```
File "mouse_server.py", line 19, in onMessage
  print(coordinates[2])
  exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range
```

Whats wrong with `print(coordinates[1])`?

## Update 1

Here is the full code:

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol, \
                                       WebSocketClientFactory
from pymouse import PyMouse

mo = PyMouse()

class MyClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, response):
        print("Server connected: {0}".format(response.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onMessage(self, msg, isBinary):
        coordinates = msg.split('/')
        print(coordinates)
        print(coordinates[1])

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    from twisted.python import log
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://localhost:4343", debug = False)
    factory.protocol = MyClientProtocol

    reactor.connectTCP("127.0.0.1", 4343, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Your exception and claimed code *don't match*. The exception tries to access `coordinates[2]`! What else doesn't match? Can we see more of your code please?

Comment: Sorry, old exception message. But it shouldn't matter since there are 4 items in the list? However, I updated my question.

Comment: Clearly `msg` doesn't always have a `/` in it. Are you 100% certain that you are looking at the correct `coordinates` being printed when that exception is thrown?

Comment: You're right... I think I've overlooked an initial message without an `/` separator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, if you are running this on a bunch of lines, there might be one input line that does not have all the expected fields. You can print the whole list before accessing that element and see the last one that appears before the exception.

Comment: Ohhh damn, I think I've overlooked an initial message without an `/` separator...

Answer (score -1):

I would personally put it into a 2D Array, this in turn makes it easier to print out certain parts of the list/array not all of it.

```
Simple2D = [['A4 Notepad','1.99'],['Clear pencil case small','0.99'],['Clear pencil case large','1.50']]
```

Printing Separate would be more convenient but to print all do -

```
for i in range(len(items)):
    for j in range(len(items[i])):
        print(items[i][j])
```

Change the variables...

Comment: This has nothing to do with the posted question. You should avoid posting garbage answers that will be deleted as eventually you will be banned from the site. Will flag this for moderator attention.